# Rails Console not reading my commands correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, console, command-line-arguments

Something is funky with my Command Line...

```
$ cd rails_projects
sh.exe": cd: rails_projets: No such file or directory
```

It changes "projects" to "projets"... why?

Comment: Just do `ls -l` to see the current directory contents, and paste the output in your post

Comment: It would be your typo.

Comment: do `pwd` and see what is your current directory. Then issue `ls -l rails*` and see if your `rails_projects` exists. Also see `ls -la` to check any hidden files or directories conflicting with that name.

Comment: That's not rails, nor ruby. That looks like a shell prompt. On Windows... What is sh.exe? Is this in Cygwin or something?